# How to print data obtained from firestore according to time stamp in flutter chat screen

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _fireStore.collection('messages').orderBy('creation',descending: true).snapshots(),
              // ignore: missing_return
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    ),
                  );
                }
                print(snapshot.data.documents);
                final messages = snapshot.data.documents;
                List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
                for (var message in messages) {
                  final messageText = message.data['text'];
                  final messageSender = message.data['sender'];

                  final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;

                  final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
                    messageText: messageText,
                    messageSender: messageSender,
                    isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
                  );
                  messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
                }
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    reverse: true,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                    children: messageBubbles,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

I am able to print the data on to the chat screen but. the chat messages are not in the ordered fashion, even though I used the time stamp method.
https://github.com/umakanth-pendyala/Chat-app-with-flutter-and-fire-base/blob/master/lib/screens/chat_screen.dart is the link to this page on GitHub

```
I/flutter ( 6842): Timestamp(seconds=1592153051, nanoseconds=815667000)
I/flutter ( 6842): Timestamp(seconds=1592152945, nanoseconds=926026000)
I/flutter ( 6842): Timestamp(seconds=1592152927, nanoseconds=592784000)
I/flutter ( 6842): Timestamp(seconds=1592151589, nanoseconds=936798000)
I/flutter ( 6842): Timestamp(seconds=1592146470, nanoseconds=674283000)
I/flutter ( 6842): Timestamp(seconds=1592110369, nanoseconds=392054000)
```

this is the output I am getting if I print the value of time stamp on the console

Comment: Instead of requiring us to set up a UI to reproduce it, can you reproduce the problem without any UI? For example: by looping over the results of your query and printing their `creation` value. If you can, edit your question to include that code **and** its output. Having minimal dependencies in your question maximizes the chance that someone can help.

Comment: Hey, as you asked i have added the output of the time stamp, yesterday I didn't work but today it works fine.

Comment: Good to hear.  I'm voting to close the question as not reproducible in that case.